# Do I have to set options with every CURL request on the same object?

Tags: php, curl

I have an app which makes two requests, one right after the other. With only one curl_init() at the beginning and all options remaining the same (except url and data, naturally) do I need to set all the options again, or does the curl object retain them? I've been all over google and stackoverflow but haven't found an answer to this question - or haven't found the right question to ask.

Comment: Why don't you test it and see? If it doesn't retain the options, then it should be observable in some way (e.g. request fails due to missing headers, or response is processed differently, or whatever, depending on what you've set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the specific options, but I just ran a quick test script and it appears the options are retained:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// request one:
echo "Sending request one..." . PHP_EOL;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stackoverflow.com");
$response1 = curl_exec($ch);

// request two:
echo "Sending request two..." . PHP_EOL;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
$response2 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "Both requests submitted." . PHP_EOL;

echo "Request 1 response:" . PHP_EOL;
echo substr($response1, 0, 50) . "..." . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

echo "Request 2 response:" . PHP_EOL;
echo substr($response2, 0, 50) . "..." . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Sending request one...
Sending request two...
Both requests submitted.
Request 1 response:
<!DOCTYPE html>


    <html class="html__respon...

Request 2 response:
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http:/...
```

If the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option was not retained after the first request, it would have reverted to its default value of `FALSE` which would have output the entire HTML page from Google immediately after the `Sending request two...` line.

It is probably worth mentioning though that some curl options set some extra properties you may not be aware of. For example, if your first request sets the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option, this implicitly also sets the request method and Content-Type and Content-Length header values. You need to be aware of this when you re-use the curl handle for the next request, if that needs to be a GET request for example.

Personally, I always create a new handle for sequential requests. If those requests need the same options, I tend to use `curl_setopt_array` with a predefined options array:

```
$options = [
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  // ...any other shared options
];

$ch1 = curl_init($url1);
curl_setopt_array($ch1, $options);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "test=test");
$response1 = curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);
var_dump($response1);

$ch2 = curl_init($url2);
curl_setopt_array($ch2, $options);
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
var_dump($response2);
```

This is a very easy way to re-use default curl options without polluting the second request with unexpected side-effects remaining from the first request.

Comment: No, it does not depend on the specific option. They are all "sticky" and will remain set until changed. You *should* try to re-use handles rather than creating new ones, so that you can take better advantage of persistent connections, caches etc.